# OOP in Python beginner issues, finding all methods of the same starting name

Tags: python, object, methods

I would like to create an abstract method in parent class which would be overridden in subclasses. This method would print all methods in the given subclass which start with 'on_'.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class abstract_class(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def get_all_on_methods(self):
        pass

class sub(abstract_class):
    an_object = sub()

    def get_all_on_methods(self):
        for attribute in dir(self):
            if attribute.startswith("on_"):
                print(attribute)

    def nothin(self):
        print("nothin")

    def on_fallback(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def on_no(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

sub.get_all_on_methods()
```

I have two problems. First, I have:

```
Unresolved reference 'sub'
```

Second, I don't know whether my approach as actually all that good.

Comment: you should remove the line ```an_object = sub()``` and change the end line to ```sub().get_all_on_methods()``` resulting in the expected output ```on_fallback
on_no```

Comment: oh thanks, I did not realise you can only instantiate an object outside of the class

Comment: You can instantiate objects inside the class, just not instances of the class currently being defined (because the class itself hasn't yet been defined). The statements the body of the class statements are executed the same as any other statements and follow the same rules (aside from complications arising from how the namespace interacts with its enclosing scope).